# C# EF List from two classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two classes:

```
   public partial class Alergy
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VaccinationAlergyID { get; set; }
        public string PHN { get; set; }
        public virtual VaccinationAlergy VaccinationAlergy { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class VaccinationAlergy
    {
        public VaccinationAlergy()
        {
            this.Alergies = new HashSet<Alergy>();
        }
        public int VaccinationAlergyID { get; set; }
        public string VaccinationAlergyName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Alergy> Alergies { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the following to get two values from these models using:

```
  var vaccination = db.Alergies.Where(x => x.PHN == phn)
  .Select(x => new { VaccinationAlergyID= x.VaccinationAlergyID,
   VaccinationAlergyName= x.VaccinationAlergy.VaccinationAlergyName}).ToList();
```

I get only the first VaccinationAlergyName the rest are the id of VaccinationAlergyName.
Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: "I get only the first VaccinationAlergyName the rest are the id of VaccinationAlergyName."

Could you please clarify this ?

Comment: The first VaccinationAlergyName is Hepatitis A, I get in the list; other VaccinationAlergyName are listed as their corresponding id value 2,5,6 ..

Comment: You have checked value in the database already it's name is correct right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 var vaccination = db.Alergies.Where(x => x.PHN == phn).Include(x=> x.VaccinationAlergy).Select(x => new { VaccinationAlergyID= x.VaccinationAlergyID,VaccinationAlergyName=x.VaccinationAlergy.VaccinationAlergyName}).ToList();
```